# How to load huge no of small files in spark on EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am loading 50 GB of text files initially partitioned in 190 text files.
I ran my spark job on that and it worked great. It took 12 minutes to complete the job.
The output of this job is again 50 GB and with default partition spark has created huge number of small files.

Now I want to run my spark job on the output files again. It's running horribly slow. After two hours I had to stop my cluster.

I debugged and found spark was busy loading files itself and that is how I identified the issue is with the huge nubmer of small files.

This is annoying as spark wants to load big files but again does not want output big file.

How to handle this situation?

I tried this

```
val rdd =sc.textFile(mainFileURL, 10).repartition(10)
```

But I encountered the problem where I was getting info from the files name; and I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

```
val get_cus_val = sqlContext.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))
```

Will changing `WholeTextFiles` work?

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(mainFileURL)
```

When I do that I get error in below line 
saying

> value contains is not a member of (String, String)

```
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("FundamentalSeriesId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
```

Can some one suggest how to handle this small file problem?

At last 
I have partitionBy columns also where i direct spark to put certain records in specific partition .But some of the partition has huge size approx. 50 GB.If I further partition the no of files will increase .

```
dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.write.partitionBy("DataPartition", "PartitionYear")
```

Comment: Do you know you can reduce the number of output files by reducing the number of partitions? If you called `rdd.coalesce(2).saveAsTextFile(path)`, you would end up with 2 files. Just be sure that memory will be sufficient to hold the data on 2 machines.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes I tried that but when I did that my job completion time went from 12 minutes to hours ...

Comment: During the first job (the one which produces too many files) is it better if  you use `coalesce` but with a number of partitions between 2 and too many? For instance 190 (or 1000).

Comment: @XavierGuihot so you are suggesting to use coalesce but with less no of partitions..

Comment: You could try with 190.

Comment: @XavierGuihot if i try with 190 then it will create 190 files in each partitionBy columns .`dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition", "PartitionYear")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not really sure which version of Spark you are running, but you use `sqlContext` and `sc.wholeTextFiles`, so I'm guessing you are running some pre-2.x version. In general Spark does not handle many small files well, and as has been suggested in comments, I too highly recommend that you reduce the number of output files first. In order to do this *without* it taking forever, you need to partition you dataframe *before* you call `.write.partitionBy`, so please try to modify you code like this:

```
dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull
  .repartition("DataPartition", "PartitionYear")
  .write
  .partitionBy("DataPartition", "PartitionYear")
  ...
```

That should speed up the job significantly :)

Comment: Thank you ...This in indeed improved performance ...Up vote for that